# Is it possible to stream audio to twitch with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, nginx, rtmp, twitch, discord.js

With [discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/topics/voice.md) you can capture audio from a voice channel. Would it be possible to use that audio to start a twitch stream? Would I need to set up a local rtmp server with nginx that points to twitch first? How could I send the audio stream to this local rtmp server if I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Itʻs possible but youʻll have to use C# or python, if you want write your own you can get started here [Twitch API - Docs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs)

But i suggest you learn a little more about JS before developing a whole twitch streaming application, itʻs not how easy you think.